# Displaying websites with WebGL in Python / PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, webgl

I'd like to write an app in Python that will display website with WebGL content. That's my script:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
webView = QtWebKit.QWebView()    
webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 591, 511))
webView.settings().setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.WebGLEnabled, True)
webView.settings().setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.AcceleratedCompositingEnabled, True)
webView.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://webglsamples.org/aquarium/aquarium.html'))
webView.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's like the "WebGLEnabled" setting doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas? Maybe you have some example code working in PyQT or PySide?